# Odoo 9 evidentio call in CRM module

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

Is it possible enable evidention call in CRM (Opportunity) in version 9.

Any solution or other free module.

Comment: Can please shade some light on What is evidention here ?

Comment: @shodowsjedi  Any simple solution for example: on button click open new pop up and here put all call history date, phone, short description...